# Getting 7zip to accept piped arguments

Tags: pipe, 7zip

I'm piping a list of files to 7zip, it does not seem to like this despite it working fine to something like cat.

```
find . -type f | grep -E '\.rar' | 7z -o/unrar/ #fails
Error: 
Incorrect command line

find . -type f | grep -E '\.rar' | cat
//fullpath/file1.rar
//fullpath/file2.rar
//fullpath/file3.rar
```

I took the first return as you see it from cat and passed it normally to 7zip as I expect that pipe does.  This worked fine

```
7z -o/unrar //fullpath/file1.rar
```

Maybe I should give up and just use tar?  I like the API for 7zip a little better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're expecting 7z to read the filenames to treat from standard input, not the command line? Are you sure you don't mean

```
7z -o/unrar $(find . -type f | grep -E '\.rar' )
```

or something like

```
find . -type f -a -name \*.rar -exec 7z -o/unrar \\{\\} \;
```

which will find all files (type f) that also match *.rar and call 7z on every filename.

Comment: Ill try it, it looks like find -execdir would be the best solution but I cant figure out how to use a negative lookbehind with their regex evaluator.  From what I understand about bash pipes, you should be able to pass them along like I did in the question.  Maybe 7zip doesn't play well with pipes